# Which in-game tracks do the Multiplayer music selections correlate to in Pokemon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, game-music-identification

While searching for or connecting with another player for a battle over wireless communications, the touchscreen allows you to select one of 11 tracks to play for the battle. Unfortunately, all of the music tracks are labelled 'Music 1', 'Music 2' etc. This isn't very helpful. I would like to know what each one refers to.

I believe that these music tracks are the same ones that can be changed at the 'Battle Maison', but they have the same unhelpful titles there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this list](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67731022) on GameFAQs, the music list is as follows:

- Music 1: Trainer battle.
- Music 2: Wild Pokémon battle.
- Music 3: Rival battle.
- Music 4: Gym Leader battle.
- Music 5: Mega Evolution Tutorial Battle (Lucario vs Lucario)
- Music 6: Team Flare battle.
- Music 7: Lysandre battle.
- Music 8: Kalos Legendaries battles.
- Music 9: Kanto (Gen 1) Legendaries battle.
- Music 10: Elite 4 member battle.
- Music 11: Champion battle.

As Trent notes, you may unlock them as you complete different battles in-game